# Translate the json response

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting problem in parsing this object. I am using json lib in android. I don't how to loop the object so that I get the list and easy pick required values.

```
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": {
            "Sentra": {
                "doors": 4,
                "transmission": "automatic"
            },
            "Maxima": {
                "doors": 4,
                "transmission": "automatic"
            }
        },
        "Ford": {
            "Taurus": {
                "doors": 4,
                "transmission": "automatic"
            },
            "Escort": {
                "doors": 4,
                "transmission": "automatic"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this out. For android, we can get id through Iterator using JSONObject. keys ().

```
JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
Iterator iterator = Obj.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
String key = (String)iterator.next();
JSONObject jObject = issueObj.getJSONObject(key);

//  getting value by
    String _pubKey = jObject.optString("Sentra");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON have a problem you use JSONObject instead of JSONArray, use this Json :

```
 {
    "cars": [
    "Nissan": [
        "Sentra": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
        "Maxima": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
    ],
    "Ford": [
        "Taurus": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"},
        "Escort": {"doors":4, "transmission":"automatic"}
    ]
]}
```

EDIT : I had a mistake in the new JSON

Comment: any other way to do this. Don't want to change the this json.

Comment: By using json lib? No. You can't parse it, it's not a correct JSON doc.

But you can parse it by hand :)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the JSON object like below

```
    for(var key in obj){
            var attrName = key;
            var attrValue = obj[key];
      }
```

Comment: is it possible in java/android using json lib, looping the object?